# How do I set different top and bottom lines of a list item based on an object's fields?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listitem

I have objects called `Vendible`s that have an `id` and a `name` (both `String`s). To represent dozens of these without actually storing dozens in memory, I have a class called `CondensedVendible`, which extends `Vendible` and adds a `count` variable (`byte`).

Currently, I'm populating my list like the example code did:

```
    setListAdapter(
            new ArrayAdapter<Vendibles.Vendible>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                Vendibles.ITEMS
            )
    );
```

This, though, just fills each list item with the return of `CondensedVendible#toString()`. Instead, I want them to look like:

```
[CondensedVendible#name]
[CondensedVendible#count] left
```

in much the same way most Android setting screens have a setting name and short description in each list item.

I've looked at [blogs](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html) and [other SO answers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F4837834%2F2-lines-in-a-listview-item&ei=z1HEU_WnOoqgyAT5oYHIDw&usg=AFQjCNG918A6oPQXC67mm6MecIMA9TitKg&sig2=aJhhU3pN1jm9ME0pRVaFBQ), but I just can't understand them! **Can anyone help me understand how to do this?**

### UPDATE

---

I think I'm close. Here's what I've got now:

### Java

```
    setListAdapter(
            new SimpleAdapter(
                    getActivity(),
                    Vendibles.toMapList(),
                    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    new String[] { Vendibles.MAP_NAME, Vendibles.MAP_COUNT },
                    new int[] { R.id.list_item_line_1, R.id.list_item_line_2 }
            )
    );

[meanwhile, in Vendibles.java...]

public static final String MAP_COUNT = "count", MAP_NAME = "name";
public static List<Map<String, String>> toMapList()
{
    List<Map<String, String>> ret = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    for(Vendible v : ITEMS) {
        if (v == null) continue; // no use trying to process notyhing
        Map<String, String> uselesslySmallMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        uselesslySmallMap.put(MAP_COUNT,
            (v instanceof CondensedVendible
                ? ((CondensedVendible) v).count
                : (byte)1
            )+"" // safer than toString, shorter than String.valueOf
        );
        uselesslySmallMap.put(MAP_NAME, v.name);

        ret.add(uselesslySmallMap);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Line 1"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_line_1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_dark" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Line 2"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_line_2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_dark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**But it now renders blank list items!** It's not like I'm passing it an empty list, because it has the right number of them, they just don't show any text!

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at simple_list_item_activated_1.xml in your android sdk? Here it is below:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

It's a single TextView. If you want a more complex custom item, then you will need to provide your own custom Item layout and list adapter.
A quick google will come up with many tutorials on how to implement your own custom items:
http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429
http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/
http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/customizing-android-listview-item-layout/
etc

Comment: You mean all those standard things I always see are all custom-made?

Comment: There's a bunch of basic ones supplied with the android SDK such as simple_list_item_1, simple_list_item_2, simple_list_item_2_single_choice etc. If these don't suit your needs then yes, you'll need to make your own custom one. Once you've done it a couple of times you'll find it's quite easy.

Comment: Is there one with two lines? I really prefer to stick with standards so users don't have to learn a new system

Comment: [TwoLineListItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.html).

Comment: Alright, I've edited my question. Thanks for your help so far, but I still need some more

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I'm adding a second answer as your Update is really asking a second question.

The second parameter in the SimpleList constructor is a List of Maps. Each of these Maps contains the data for an item.
In your case each of these maps will contain 2 entries. The first mapping the item's name to the key "name", the second mapping the count to the key "count".

Say for example your Vendible class has a name field and a count field like this:

```
public class Vendible {
    public String name;
    public int count;
}
```

And vendibles is a SparseArray of your Vendible class. You can then populate your list of HashMaps with your items:

```
SparseArray<Vendible> vendibles = new SparseArray<Vendible>;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> vendibleList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
...

HashMap<String, String> vendibleItem;
Vendible vendible;
for(int i = 0; i < vendibles.size(); i++) {
    vendibleItem = new HashMap<String, String>;

    vendible = vendibles.valueAt(i);
    vendibleItem.put("name", vendible.name);
    vendibleItem.put("count", vendible.count);

    vendibleList.add(vendibleItem)
}
```

You can then pass this populated list to the constructor for the SimpleAdapter:

```
setListAdapter(
       new SimpleAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                vendibleList,
                android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                new String[] { "name", "count" },
                new int[] { R.id.list_item_line_1, R.id.list_item_line_2 }
        )
);
```

If you're still having problems then post your code where you populate your list, to pass to the SimpleAdapter constructor.

Comment: sorry, I should've posted `Vendibles#toMapList()`. Am I doing it right?